# Dash ability not applying any sideways force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a dash ability, it works fine as a monobehavior, but not as a scriptable object.

My character uses abilities by using cards. The cards are Game Objects, they have a "Card" scriptable object attached with the cards info, which has a specific Dash ability that inherits from a general "CardAbility" scriptable object. When I test the ability directly as a MonoBehavior it works fine (needs fine tuning offcourse), but now it is only propelling the player upwards, but there is no sideways motion at all. I fire off the ability from a Deck script, in a separate Deck empty game object, this part works fine, so the ability is firing off properly, just not working as it should.

Here is the ability and the important parts in other scripts for it to work:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Card Abilities/Dash")]
public class Dash : CardAbility
{
    [SerializeField] private float upwardsSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float dashSpeed;

    public override void CastAbility()
    {
        CastDash();
    }

    private void CastDash()
    {
        AssignComponents();

        if (!playerController.isFlipped)
        {
            playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(-dashSpeed, upwardsSpeed);
        }
        else if (playerController.isFlipped)
        {
            playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed, upwardsSpeed);
        }
        
    }
}
```

The scriptable object from which it inherits:

```
public class CardAbility : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private string abilityName;

    public float abilityDuration;

    public PlayerData playerData;
    public Rigidbody2D playerRb;
    public BoxCollider2D playerColl;
    public PlayerController playerController;

    public void AssignComponents()
    {
        if(playerData != null)
        {
            playerRb = playerData.playerRb;
            playerColl = playerData.playerColl;
            playerController = playerData.playerController;
        }
    }

    public virtual void CastAbility()
    {
        //Default ability code here:
    }
}
```

PlayerData scriptable object which captures the players components for when an ability is cast:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "PlayerData", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/PlayerData")]
public class PlayerData : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] float defaultHealth = 100f;

    [HideInInspector] public GameObject player;
    [HideInInspector] public float health;

    [HideInInspector] public Rigidbody2D playerRb;
    [HideInInspector] public BoxCollider2D playerColl;
    [HideInInspector] public PlayerController playerController;

    public void ResetData()
    {
        player = null;
        health = defaultHealth;
        playerRb = null;
        playerColl = null;
        playerController = null;
    }
}
```

The part in my PlayerController which assigns the components to the PlayerData:

```
    private void OnEnable()
        {
            playerData.player = gameObject;
            playerData.playerColl = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
            playerData.playerRb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            playerData.playerController = gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        }
    
    private void OnDisable()
        {
            playerData.ResetData();
        }

private void Update()
    {
        
        if (movementAllowed)
        {
            dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded() || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && IsGrounded()) //check if grounded to allow jumping
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            }
        }
        
        UpdateAnimation();
    }
```

I can't figure out if there is an error somewhere which doesn't connect the players components properly. Also, if there is any suggestions for a better structure in how I connect the code I'm open to suggestions though, my main issue is understanding why the player is not affected as intended, which would make implementing different abilities in the future pretty troublesome.

Comment: It looks like your movement script preserves rb.velocity.y but overwrites the x velocity, so your dash speed is probably getting immediately written over.

Comment: Yes, I simply set movementAllowed to false while the dash happens and set it back to true when it ends and that works fine.